# Why not just fix this answer instead of trying to nuke it?

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users

https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/139204/4188 took me about ten seconds to copy-paste Victorinox Spectra into Google Images and drop an image into the answer. There are four upvotes on the mod's comment ... so that's five people who didn't do it. And someone(s) downvoted it as well.

It is a *great* answer, come now, it does answer the question exactly, what it deserves is upvotes.

Comment: Is it really a _great_ answer?

Comment: Yes, it shows the very product the question looked for from a well known, reputable brand (and it's a very unusual product, otherwise I don't think the question wouldn't stay open).

Answer (score 8):

Besides the teaching part, as well written in the answer by @JoErNanO, it is not always possible to search for and edit in photos. I do handle a lot of moderator work on the small screen of my phone which is not suitable for search, cut, copy, paste and edit.

Besides, general users nor mods should be required to do a search to see whether an answer has merit.

Comment: +1 For the last sentence, it could suffice as an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes it makes sense to teach new users how to do things rather than doing those things ourselves. It helps shape the site and preserve the quality standards we aim for.

In this specific case there's also the possibility that the user might be a spammer - new registration, first post, recommending a product. One way to verify is to see if the user is willing to improve their post and make it fit for our site. For all these reasons it makes sense to ask for modifications rather than to apply them ourselves.

No need to start polemics on mod behaviour again.